# Simulate N5010 laptop on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, virtualization

I have an `N5010 Dell Inspiron` laptop from an old time. Due to some problems, I cannot install an operating system on it.

I don't want to explain the details of the problem to avoid someone bypass the answer. What I want to do is to install the operating system on the hard disk from virtualbox and then move the hard-disk back to the laptop. The problem is that an operating system cannot be installed by a system and then work on another system. Therefore, I should have a virtual machine very similar to my laptop.

My laptop's spec is

```
CPU : Intel Core(TM) i3 CPU M380 @ 2.53 GHz
Memory : 8GB
HDD : 1TB
Mother Board :   09909 -1 D15 A14 MB
```

The questions are

1. Can I simulate such a system on virtualbox?
2. Are these information enough to make the systems identical enough for OS to work?

Comment: VirtualBox cannot simulate systems. It literally only have support for only two chipset, none of them updated. Can't you boot from any device? Not even a PXE server (i.e. from network)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I can boot but after one or two minutes, my laptop overheats. I suspect it is because of the BIOS. It seems an OS takes over the control of cooling system better but I need to install OS first where 1 or 2 minutes are not enough. I would like to upgrade the BIOS. But, I need to instal OS first.